GE Profile Dishwasher - start button not working
we have a GE profile dishwasher model number: PDT715SYN5FS. We bought it new and this was working fine for about a year. For the past couple of months, the start button doesn't work occasionally. Every other button works. And for the past two weeks, it doesn't work at all. If we reset the power, it used to work after 6-12 hours. But now it doesn't turn on at all or start the dishwasher.
Has someone faced this issue? Repair options from GE appear to be in $200+ range (120$ for visit and potentially more for parts). We are not happy that the new dishwasher is giving this problem just outside warranty window.
Is it the control board issue? While researching I found there are two boards - one under the dishwasher and another for touch controls. Not sure if any of these could be faulty/how to find which one.
I am handy with tools/electrical items and curious to diagnose/repair this issue. Hope someone could point us in the right direction. Thanks!


Do you think it thinks the door is open perhaps?

Good one, but no. :) The buttons don't work either ways. It used to work even with door open.

I think it should only work with the door closed, so who knows, maybe something is still amiss...?  Good luck! :)

Possibly, the contacts inside the start switch are dirty, possibly from the manufacturer, or some object inside the switch is exuding some substance, like the silicone pushbuttons on remotes do when they're not baked properly and prevent the buttons from working.
I would try to remove and open the button panel control board (with the dishwasher power turned off at the breaker and the breaker locked out) and see if the start switch cab be disassembled and cleaned.

Last year had the same problem with my GE dishwasher. After running a simple diagnostic I was able to determine that my problem was in the user interface panel which I ordered and replaced without a lot of hassle. It took about 45 minutes. FYI - Before I diagnosed the problem I was able to temporarily get it to work by cutting power to the DW by unplugging it. This reset it and allowed it to work for a few days before it would once again shut down. You might try it.
If you do a search with your model # and the issue you are having you will be directed to several GE parts suppliers. Select one that provides repair videos. My GE dishwasher is a different model # than yours but here is the link to the video I used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxPpRjxVyPo
I had to first remove the base plate to access the lower board. From there the video will explain how to run a fairly simple test to determine whether the problem is in the upper user interface or the lower control board.
The lower one is easier to replace but the upper one is not too bad either. It does require dismantling the door but not too bad.
Good luck.

Thanks HoneyDo. It would help if you can share the link that shows how to diagnose if the issue is in board under dishwasher or on the one at the top door with touch controls.

My model # is different from yours but I edited my answer with the link to the video I used. Also note that I was able to reset the DW and get it working temporarily by unplugging it. You might try that.

Awesome, thanks!
